# RPi Motion FFMPEG Recording falls behind

Tags: motion, ffmpeg

My Raspberry Pi is set up using Motion to broadcast a live stream that I can view from a browser, additionally, it is storing a time-lapse .mpeg file of images taken every 2 seconds.

The streaming functionality works like a charm and the time-lapse works great for a short while. After a period of ~5 hours (Streaming and recording) my time-lapse has fallen behind! Watching the lapse shows me that the most recent recorded image is from about the 3 hour mark, yet the stream in the browser shows the correct time.

Any idea why the FFMPEG is falling behind and how to remedy this?

Comment: I will try reducing frequency of images for the time-lapse from every 2 seconds to every 5 seconds to see if this helps. But, having frequent images is nice as it is more clear/smooth; what is happening on the recording

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this issue I reduced the rate at which I am capturing images for the timelapse video. It appears that by reducing the capture rate There is no longer a write queue that is blocked up.